# Error in querying embedded json using apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

**donutTest.json**  (in my local system at /home/dev):

```
{
   "id":"0001",
   "type":"donut",
   "name":"Cake",

   "batter":{
            "id":"1001",
            "type":"Regular"
           },

   "topping":[
             { "id":"5001", "type":"None"},
             { "id":"5002", "type":"Glazed"}  
             ]
 }
```

This query is working fine.

```
 select topping[0].id as topping_id, topping[3].type as topping_type from dfs.`/home/dev/donutTest.json`;
```

But when I tried:

```
select batter.id as batter_id, batter.type as batter_type from dfs.`/home/dev/donutTest.json`;
```

It's showing error.

> Table 'batter' not found

`topping[0]` and `batter` both are embedded document still error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a table alias and then reference that in the select statement.

```
select donut.batter.id as batter_id, donut.batter.type as batter_type from dfs.`/home/dev/donutTest.json` as donut;
```

This way Drill has a reference to the actual table alias and then the nested structure underneath.

Comment: why table notation is not needed in case of topping[0].id ?

Comment: This isn't a very enlightening answer, but it comes from the docs http://apache.github.io/drill/docs/json-data-model/#analyzing-json, which say that  y, y[z] or y[z].x references are not ambiguous, but Drill currently explicitly requires a table prefix for referencing a field inside another field (t.y.z).